# SeekBar not moving stuck

Tags: android

i simple add seekbar then run the but seekbar stuck at one place not moving when swap through touch

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/timesTableSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Try width = match_parent

Comment: paste your xml full code here with other constraints layout

Comment: when i add seekbar its work fine but when i add listView uder seekbar it make seekbar stuck

Answer (score 0):

first you should set value of max property in seekBar:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="13dp"
        android:minHeight="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/shape_seekbar_progress"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:thumb="@drawable/ic_seek_thumb"/>
```

and then in java class :

```
   seekBar = activity.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());//before all
```

Comment: when i add seekbar its work fine but when i add listView uder seekbar it make seekbar stuck

Comment: I Think you should use RecyclerView insted of listView , please  paste your xml file code here

Answer (score 0):

You must remove listView and check with emulator is ok. ListView must remove from xml and java file. Next if work only seekBar, return to android studio xml view, and add again listView, change id, check with emulator is work seekBar. If work, add listView in java file. I have same problem, and in my project its work.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered that issue and I hope this helps:
If you are using a ListView in the XML I would suggest making sure that the SeekBar and the ListView aren't overlapping each other, that solved it for me.